# Need help solving this eq $\ln(\sqrt{x^{2}+1})=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, numerical-methods

I'm trying to draw the graph of the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln(\sqrt{x^{2}+1})-1}{x}$ (from Demidovich's book problems in mathematical analysis). 
When I do the derivative, in order to find the extrema, I need to solve the equation 
$$\ln(\sqrt{x^{2}+1})-1=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$$
Using  Geogebra i see that the curves intersect each other in some point $t\in (7,7.5)$ but I  do not know how to get it.

I would be happy with any  idea to solve it.

Comment: By observation one may note that a simple root is given by $x=0$ since in this case the RHS becomes trivially zero whereas the LHS becomes $\ln(\sqrt{0^2+1})=\ln(\sqrt{1})=\ln(1)$ which also equals zero. It seems like the other roots can be obtained by using the Lambert function as you can see [here on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%5Cln(%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%7D)%3D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%7D%7Bx%5E2%2B1%7D).

Comment: Hello, $x=0$ is not in the domain, and $x=0$ does not satisfy the required eq.
I'll read about the Lambert function. Thanks.

Comment: Well of course $x=0$ is not within the domain of $f(x)$ but in fact it does satisfies the given equation concerning the first derivative.

Comment: oh, yes, you are right sorry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform to 
$$
\frac{1+x^2}{e^2}=e^{-\frac2{1+x^2}}
$$
Now bring the right side to the form $ue^u$ with $u=-\frac2{1+x^2}$
$$
-2e^{-2}=-\frac{2}{1+x^2}e^{-\frac2{1+x^2}}
$$
By definition of the Lambert-W function, $u=W(v)$ solves $v=ue^u$. For $-e^{-1}<v<0$ there are two solutions, one in $(-\infty,-1)$ and one in $(-1,0)$. Obviously the first root is here $-2=u=-\frac{2}{1+x^2}$, which solves to $x=0$. The other solution is $u=W_0(-2/e^2)=-0.40637573995995996..$ and this can now be solved for $x$.

Comment: Oh really thanks, until now i see that i wrote wrong the condición but with your answer i can solve the problema.